# Mongoid composite query

Tags: mongoid, criteria, composite

I'm kind of a newbie to mongoid, I have a problem querying the db for inner relations:

this is the first model of whom I wish to create a query

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid

  has_many :hosted_meals, class_name:'Meal', inverse_of: :host
  has_and_belongs_to_many :followers, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :following
 .
 .
 .
end
```

Second model

```
  class Meal
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid

    field :privacy, type: String, default: 'p'
    belongs_to :host, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :hosted_meals
```

Im trying to create a mongo query that does the following:

1. return all meals of type 'p'
2. return all meals are of type 'f' and their host is in the current user's followers, something like this:

Meal.where(:privacy => 'f', :host_id.in => )